# action script 3 xml parsing

Tags: xml, flash

```
var xml:XML;
var name:string;
var elements:XMLList = xml..*[name]
```

What does `..*[]` do?

I have a xml that looks like:

```
<tag1 attr1="a"> 
  <tag2 attr2="b"> 
  </tag2> 
</tag1>
```

why does `xml..*["tag2"]` return null?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I'm not used to access xml nodes through strings.

The `..` operator means [desendants](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#descendant_accessor) (similar to the [children()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#children%28%29) method).

The `*` is a wildcard, meaning all nodes on that level.

The `[]` would be array access notation, but since you've got E4X support
in as3, I don't see that often.

You can easily do this:

```
var xml:XML = <tag1 attr1="a"> 
  <tag2 attr2="b" /> 
</tag1>;

var elements:XMLList = xml.tag2;
trace(elements.toXMLString());//prints: <tag2 attr2="b"/>
```